# I want to show only a part of the information of the register in the template

Tags: python, django, list, templates, django-templates

I'm working on a forum and I have a list of the new messages, But I show all the massage that I get from the database, what I want is only show like 2 o 3 lines of the information and have a link that will show all the message to the user in other window.

list.html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load crispy_forms_tags%}
{%block content%}
<table width="90%" border="2" class="table">
{% for register in object_list%}
    <tr>
       <th class="info">Title</th>
       <th class="info">Message</th>
       <th class="info">Date</th>
       <th class="info">Time</th>
       <th class="info">User</th>
       <th class="info">&nbsp</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{register.tit}}</td>
        <td>{{register.mensaje}}</td>
        <td>{{register.date}}</td>
        <td>{{register.time}}</td>
        <td>{{register.user}}</td>
        <td align="center" class="warning">
         <a href="{% url 'blogurls:answer' title.pk%}">Answer</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
</table>
{%endblock content%}
```

Comment: So what's your question? You don't know how to do it? What have you tried?

Comment: what I want is only show like 2 o 3 lines of the information, I don't know how to do it. like if I have this:    Link functionality caveat This class uses pointer-events: none to try to disable the link functionality of <a>s, but that CSS property is not yet standardized and isn't fully supported in Opera 18 and below, or in Internet Explorer 11.   I just want to show 2 o 3 lines of that info, I don't know how to do in the template.

Comment: What do you mean 2 or 3 lines of information? For each of your record? For only 2 to 3 items in your `object_list`? If it's the second case you could just in your views.py do `object_list = object_list[:3]` to return only 3 messages to the template, then add another view to show everything, right?

Comment: Yes that what I want, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use two build-in generic class based views and a template tags to do the tricks.

A [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) for show all messages stored in the database and a [truncatechars](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) or a [truncatewords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords) for print only a part of the content. Then a link to a [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) for show the entire content in a new dedicated page.

I hope it will help.

Regards,